# How to calculate the first Chern class (concrete simple example)?

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

I have been finding a good source on computing first Chern class of a manifold (e.g.Riemannian) but I just couldn't find a single example of how to compute in terms of local coordinates. I wanted to understand what does it represents, and when it is positive, zero or negative what does these means ?
Deeply appreciated if someone could provide a detail calculation to get the first Chern class of a simple manifold. I just know that it is a cohomology class.

Comment: There is an example on the wikipedia article in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class#The_complex_tangent_bundle_of_the_Riemann_sphere)

Comment: @Didier Thank you. But I still have no background on complex geometry. May I ask how to obtain the curvature 2-form just from the metric ? Thank you.

Comment: To even talk about the first Chern class of a manifold, you need an (almost) complex manifold.